# How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA to format block comments like Eclipse does?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

How can I configure IntelliJ (for Groovy and Java) to format regular non-Javadoc block comments like Eclipse (with a `*` preceding each line)?

I'm pretty new to IntelliJ, and I haven't noticed a code formatter setting that seems applicable.

**EXAMPLES**

This is how IntelliJ formats these comments by default (which I think is particularly ugly):

```
/*
This
is
a block comment.
 */
```

This is how Eclipse formats these comments by default, and what I'd like IntelliJ to do:

```
/*
 * This
 * is
 * a block comment.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly enable this in IntelliJ IDEA.

Idea does this just for JavaDoc comments. When you start your comment with /**, Idea will automatically add * to each new line when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.